# How can i change file directory's name related to an instance's field too after the field get updated in Django's model

Tags: django, model, crud, imagefield, filefield

good day everyone, i am a self learner and quite new to django and i am facing some questions currently, i created a model which will have images upload to a self-defined directory as like this:

class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):

```
def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):
    self.delete(name)
    return name
```

class DealerList(models.Model):

```
def user_dir_folder(instance, filename):
    return 'dealerImg/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.dealerCompanyName, filename)

dealerCompanyName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
Cert = models.ImageField(storage=OverwriteStorage(), upload_to=user_dir_folder)
Img = models.ImageField(storage=OverwriteStorage(), upload_to=user_dir_folder)
```

and i installed ‘django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig’ into the settings file to cleanup those related files in case if an instance is deleted (but the empty folder stay existed which i dont know how to deal with yet, but this is second question).

now what i am facing is, if an instance’s ‘dealerCompanyName’ field is updated, the folder which created named with the ‘dealerCompanyName’ won’t get updated along (also django will delete those uploaded files that cant match any instance now after ‘dealerCompanyName’ is updated since i installed cleanup, but this is the third question),
what i wanna ask is, is there anyway to update that folder’s name too if ‘dealerCompanyName’ field get updated?
by the way if there are answer for the second and third questions mentioned above will be very very appreciated since i will face them very soon.
Hopefully could get some solutions since i have tried for long time but none is working. Many Thanks!

Comment: Why would the file get deleted just because `dealerCompanyName` got changed? That's not how image / file fields work, the image field actually _stores the path to the file_ so the change to another field does not matter. Also [Cool URIs don't change](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI) (Since those files also get a url so it's best not to change their url)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat because i installed django_cleanup and what it will do is cleaning up files that have no match with any exist instances automatically so that whenever any instance get deleted by user django will delete related files as well (so far i know by initial django will keep those files even after the instance is no more exist and this is to support role back)

Comment: The reason i wish to change it is because i am using dealerCompanyName value as those files' path from frontend, so if user updated the dealerCompanyName, these file will not be found from frontend since the path has changed.

Comment: Getting the url of an image / file field is as simple as: `dealer_list_instance.Cert.url` The field is in reality a `CharField` behind the scenes which stores the files path. "django_cleanup" will **not delete** the file because you updated a different field it will only delete since this field _still_ points to that file.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat this could be a good way to prevent them from getting deleted, but if a user updated dealerCompanyName field, now those files directory name is not as same as the company name anymore (althought i still can get those images from frontend now), and i think this might leads to a confusion when i mange those files from backend?
i am thinking of is there any way that can update the directory’s name as well when dealerCompanyName get updated.

Comment: If we first ignore about the image deletion part (which related to django_cleanup) and let say I created a model instance named ‘Kedai Makanan Rosli’,now I got a new directory that stored cert and image with ‘Kedai Makanan Rosli’ in django backend.

Comment: At some point Rosli wish to change his company name into ‘Rosli Food’, so he updates ‘dealerCompanyName’ field, but from the backend side, that directory’s name still remains ‘Kedai Makanan Rosli’. Although I can use another field as the upload directory name to get those images, but it is not matching to the company name anymore from the backend, if I have let say hundred cases like this one, it could be a big problem.